# Does proving undecidability implies that H is RE-Complete

Tags: undecidability, halting-problem

If I want to show that H is RE-Complete is it enough to show it's undecidable? or should I prove something else alongeside?

$H$ is the halting problem: $H = \{<p,x>|p \textit{ halts on } x\}$\

Comment: In fact, there is quite a bit of structure between "decidable" and "RE-complete" - see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138823/are-the-sets-in-sigma-p-or-pi-p-totally-ordered/138854#138854).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not enough.

For a language $L$ to be $RE$-complete, one needs to show two things:

1. $L\in RE$
2. For any $L'\in RE$, it holds that $L'\le_m L$ (there is a many-to-one reduction between $L'$ and $L$).

An implication of this, is that any $RE$-complete language is also undecidable. But not the other way around.

Comment: how do I show the second property ?

Comment: Use the fact that $L'\in RE$ and hence there is some TM $M$ such that $L(M)=L'$.